# Open file dialog in cocoa application using Xamarin/XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, modal-dialog

I am building a cocoa desktop application using Xamarin/XCode (I am new to this). I need to implement an OpenFileDialog like feature.

[image: This is my application window]

When I click on "Load File", a file browser should pop up and should let me select a file. After I select and press "OK", it should display the file path in the Text field on the left side. I have tried implementing this using the below code, but the file browser does not pop up. What have I missed here?

```
@synthesize LocationText = _LocationText;

@synthesize MazeSolutionText = _MazeSolutionText;

static NSURL * openFiles()
{
    //NSArray * fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"txt",nil];
    NSOpenPanel* panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [panel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
    [panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
    [panel setFloatingPanel:YES];
    //[panel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
    if([panel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK)
    {
        return [panel URL];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (IBAction)LoadFileClicked:(id)sender {

    NSURL * path = openFiles();

    _LocationText.stringValue = path.absoluteString;
}
```

Comment: `NSOpenPanel` returns an array of `NSURL` objects, so you should be returning `[[panel URLs] lastObject]` from your if statement. Otherwise it seems like your code is correct

Comment: @AlexanderNorth I made that change. But, nothing comes up when I click on the "Load File" button. Am I triggering the launch of modal dialog correctly here?

Comment: Are you sure the button is connected to the method itself? Add a breakpoint in the `openFiles()` method and see if the application stops

Comment: It working now. Thanks :) I am using Xamarin and XCode, so there was some mismatch. Fixed it.